# Passing GridView Parameters to Stored Proc

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm working with some new concepts I haven't dealt with before, so I might be over complicating this.

I have a GridView that populates from a 5 Table Join. Each column represents one of the 5 tables in the Join. The Functionality I am trying to achieve is this:

1. User selects the autogenerated Edit LinkButton
2. User Edits One or more Cells in the Row
3. User selects the autogenerated Update LinkButton
4. Params are passed to the Stored Proc which updates the effected tables.

I have a couple uncertainties about how to proceed.
If I were querying the Update directly I would need to pass the ID, changed text and a foreign key ID from another column.
So my question is how do I get the GridView UpdateCommand to pass the entire row's data to stored Proc?
I currently have set up the Stored Proc with an additional param that I was using to determine which table needed to be updated, but since it could be multiple tables, I am thinking this is the wrong approach. Here is my GV, DSN, and SP.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"
    runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    EnableModelValidation="True"
    AllowSorting="True" 
    EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True"
    allowpaging="True"
    pagesize="26"
    ondatabound="GridView1_DataBound">    

        <Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="True"
 ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Manufacturer" HeaderText="Manufacturer"   
SortExpression="Manufacturer" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PriModel" HeaderText="PriModel" 
SortExpression="PriModel" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SecModel" HeaderText="SecModel"  
SortExpression="SecModel" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Form" HeaderText="FormFactor" 
SortExpression="Form" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active" 
SortExpression="Active"/>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />                
        </Columns>
       </asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" DataSourceMode="DataSet"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:inventory_v2ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT dbo.Models.ID,dbo.Models.Active, 
    dbo.Models_PriModels.PriModel, dbo.Models_SecModels.SecModel, 
    dbo.Models_OEMs.Manufacturer, dbo.Models_FormFactor.Form
    FROM dbo.Models INNER JOIN dbo.Models_FormFactor ON 
    dbo.Models.FormFactor = dbo.Models_FormFactor.ID INNER JOIN
    dbo.Models_OEMs ON dbo.Models.Manufacturer = dbo.Models_OEMs.ID INNER JOIN
    dbo.Models_PriModels ON dbo.Models.PriModel = dbo.Models_PriModels.ID AND   
    dbo.Models_OEMs.ID = dbo.Models_PriModels.Manufacturer INNER JOIN
    dbo.Models_SecModels ON dbo.Models.SecModel = dbo.Models_SecModels.ID AND 
    dbo.Models_PriModels.ID = dbo.Models_SecModels.PriModel ORDER BY dbo.Models.ID 
    DESC"
    UpdateCommand="Procedure_UpdateModelsTables" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure"
    OnUpdated="OnDSUpdatedHandler"   
    InsertCommand="">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

    CREATE PROCEDURE <Procedure_UpdateModelsTables> 

    <@Param int>,
    <@ManufacturerID int>,
    <@Manufacturer varchar(50)>,
    <@PriModelID int>,
    <@PriModel varchar(50)>,
    <@SecModelID int>,
    <@SecModel varchar(50)>,
    <@FormID int>,
    <@Form varchar(50)>,
    <@ModelsID int>,
    <@Active char(1)>,
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    --SELECT <@Param1, sysname, @p1>, <@Param2, sysname, @p2>
    IF @param = 1     
        exec SP_OEMTable @ManufacturerID,@Manufacturer;
    IF @param = 2
       exec SP_PriModelsTable @PriModelID,@PriModel;
    IF @param = 3     
        exec SP_SecModelsTable @SecModelID,@SecModel;
    IF @param = 4
       exec SP_FormsTable @FormID,@Form;
    IF @param = 5
       exec SP_ModelsTable @ModelsID,@Active;

END

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_OEMTable
    @ManufacturerID int,
    @Manufacturer varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN  
    UPDATE Models_OEMs SET Manufacturer = @Manufacturer WHERE ID = @ManufacturerID;
END

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_PriModelsTable
    @PriModelID int,
    @ManufacturerID int,
    @PriModel varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN  
    UPDATE Models_PriModels SET PriModel = @PriModel WHERE ID = @PriModelID AND Manufacturer = @ManufacturerID;
END
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_SecModelsTable
    @SecModelID int,
    @PriModelID int,
    @SecModel varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN  
    UPDATE Models_SecModels SET SecModel = @SecModel WHERE ID = @SecModelID AND PriModel = @PriModelID;
END
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_FormsTable
    @FormID int,
    @Form varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN  
    UPDATE Models_FormFactor SET Form = @Form WHERE ID = @FormID;
END
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_ModelsTable
    @ModelsID int,
    @Active char(1)
AS
BEGIN  
    UPDATE Models SET Active = @Active WHERE ID = @ModelsID;
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial is what I used to learn this process :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24085/Insert-Update-Delete-with-Gridview-Simple-Way

Comment: That is completely irrelevant. That only works if you have to update 1 table or a 1 to 1 view.

Comment: On update you could fire a stored proc that does that for you. Lay that off on sql server.

Comment: @ briskovich that's what I'm attempting to do, but passing the Params from ASP to SQL without doing a codebehind is what is confusing me.

Comment: well that is the problem. I do grids from code behind only. You have the most control and then you can make your update event anything you want. That is why I posted that tutorial. I don't think you can do what you are trying to do without code behind.

Comment: There is a way to do it. http://forums.asp.net/t/1108433.aspx/1   However, it won't work in my situation because the cell value contains no link to the originating table ID. It gets swapped out by my JOIN. The only way I see is grabbing the cell value for the row and running a select on each value to get the original ID from each respective table, then pushing all 10 params to the stored Proc. Yuck.

Comment: Can't you just select all the variables you need for your s proc and then pass them with the update event of the grid?? You can select whatever you need when you bind the grid. You don't have to show all the columns if you don't want to.

Comment: Yeah, Well, crap. I have to refer back to the first sentence in this post "so I might be over complicating this."